# What's "loading" method for $.post()?

Tags: jquery, post, callback

I'm using $.post method as below to load more products in page. But as I learned 
from `https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/` page, it seems there is no method to have `loading' while data is loading.

Is there any other way to show `loading`?

```
$(document).ready(function(){                
    $(window).bind('scroll',fetchMore);
});

fetchMore = function (){
    var productClass = $("#content > .row > div.product-layout").prop("class");

    if (( $(window).scrollTop() >= $(document).height()-$(window).height()-300 ) && (page <= total_pages)){
        lastpage = (page == total_pages) ? 1 : 0;
        page++;

        $('#moreHolder').text('loading');

        $(window).unbind('scroll',fetchMore);

        $.post('index.php?route=product/productx' + _url + '&page=' + page + '&productClass=' + productClass,
        function(data) {
           if(data.length>10){
                $(data).insertBefore($('#moreHolder'));
                $(window).bind('scroll',fetchMore);
           }
        })
        .always(function() {
            $('#moreHolder').text('');
        });
        ;
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't that what your code is already doing?:  `$('#moreHolder').text('loading');`

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can show a loading message when the request begins

```
$(document).ready(function(){                
    $(window).bind('scroll',fetchMore);
});

fetchMore = function (){
    var productClass = $("#content > .row > div.product-layout").prop("class");

    if (( $(window).scrollTop() >= $(document).height()-$(window).height()-300 ) && (page <= total_pages)){
        lastpage = (page == total_pages) ? 1 : 0;
        page++;

        $('#moreHolder').text('loading');

        $(window).unbind('scroll',fetchMore);
        //Here show the message of loading...
        $.post('index.php?route=product/productx' + _url + '&page=' + page + '&productClass=' + productClass,
        function(data) {
           if(data.length>10){
                //And then here hide the message shown before
                $(data).insertBefore($('#moreHolder'));
                $(window).bind('scroll',fetchMore);
           }
        })
        .always(function() {
            $('#moreHolder').text('');
        });
        ;
    }
}
```

Basically you have to show the message before the request begins and hide it when the request ends or fails

Hope this helps :)

Comment: The code already does that... `$('#moreHolder').text('loading');`

Comment: Yes, you are right Kardo. David, you are right, I did not see that piece of code. Sorry